# function is constantly changing the value and the value should be fixed

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

hi I have a problem including this function in my code because the return of the function is id=1.
but after changing the value it keeps returning the value of id=1 and seconds later it shows me id=2 and then it keeps returning id=1 when it should only show the value of id=2.

```js
function updateMap() {
  var Buslocation =
    "http://localhost/getsts.php?xid=" + id;
  setTimeout(updateMap, 3000)
  console.log(Buslocation)
};
updateMap();
```

[this is the code before the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wprn.png) 
this is the code before the function

[code returned after changing id value
which should only be 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHYyp.png) 
code returned after changing id value
which should only be 3

Comment: The function doesn't change the value of `id`, that must be changing somewhere else. The function just uses whatever the current value of that global variable is.

Comment: The function doesn't return anything. `console.log()` is not the same as `return`.

Comment: As @Barmar said, the value of the `id` variable is being assigned elsewhere outside of the `updateMap()` function. Check your code for places where the variable's value might be changing.

Comment: You might have functions that  intend to use `id` locally, but fail to declare it as a local variable with `var` or `let`. Local variables should always be declared. And you should also avoid using such simple names for global variables -- use something more descriptive and reuse is less likely.